# Reshape dataframe (columns to values)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how can I transform this:

```
      Name   jan     fev
0   A53AAA  50.0    75.0
1   A65AAA   0.0   100.0
2   A69AAA  90.5    58.3
```

in that:

```
  NAME   MT  SCORE
A53AAA  jan   50.0
A53AAA  fev   75.0
A65AAA  jan    0.0
A65AAA  fev  100.0
A69AAA  jan   90.5
A69AAA  fev   58.3
```

already tried with stack, unstack, pd.pivot_table and df.pivot and nothing...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'], var_name='MT', value_name='SCORE')
```

If changing the case of the column names is important you can add:

```
(pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'], var_name='MT', value_name='SCORE')
   .rename(columns=str.upper))
```

or

```
(pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'], var_name='MT', value_name='SCORE')
   .rename(columns={'Name': 'NAME'}))
```

Comment: You should print a [pandas reshaping cheat sheet](https://pandas.pydata.org/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf) ;)